# mod_evasive me bloquea la ip de mi servidor siempre

Tags: linux, centos

He instalado `mod_evasive` en mi CentOS 7.3 y así probar el Perl de pruebas.

Tal y como esperaba, me lanza el error 403.
Modifiqué el archivo de configuración de *evasive* para que salte cuando recargan la página dos veces en menos de 2 segundos (a modo de prueba desde un navegador).

Resulta que `mod_evasive` está bloqueando la IP del servidor y no la del ordenador que hace las peticiones.

Es decir, si salta el módulo no bloquea la IP del que accede (cliente) sino la de acceso (servidor), quedando el error 403 para todo el mundo.

¿Qué está pasando?

¿Es una mala instalación o me estoy perdiendo algo?

añadir que uso apache junto a ngnix

caracteristicas:
SO: ‪CentOS Linux 7.3.1611 (Core)‬
Plesk Onyx 17.5.3

Comment: @GDP nótsese que [tu edición](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/62429) usa ', cuando para `escribir así`  debes poner la tilde abierta. Ten en cuenta por cierto que este formato es útil para cosas concretas, ponerlo en todo dificulta la lectura.

Comment: @fedorqui al ser solo texto, lo habia editado desde el word... :P pero me ha cambiado las tildes al pegarlo aqui. Fallo mio por no revisar la edición.

Comment: @GDP date cuenta que puedes editar aquí mismo, pues debajo irás viendo cómo queda en tiempo real. ¡Mucho mejor! :)